# Spring boot internalization does not work per request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I know this question might have an answer but am a newbie to spring boot. I need to do internalization to my rest endpoints and I followed [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/spring-boot-rest-internationalization-9ab3fce2489) blog to implement internalization but the problem is one. The language does not change per request it only change only after application launch that is suppose at launch in my post man the language was fr that will work but after I change fr to pt (Portuguese) it does not pick pt it still remains with fr. Here is my code that am working with. I have created 4 different messages.properties that is messages_fr.properties, messages_pt.properties, messages_sw.properties under resources dir

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
        implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(
            new Locale("en"),
            new Locale("pt"),
            new Locale("sw"),
            new Locale("fr"));

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        System.out.println("header:"+headerLang);
        return headerLang == null || headerLang.isEmpty()
                ? Locale.getDefault()
                : Locale.lookup(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(headerLang), LOCALES);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rs.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
        rs.setBasename("messages");

        rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return rs;
    }

}
```

And Translator class

```
@Component
public class LanguageTranslator {

    private static ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    LanguageTranslator(ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource) {
        LanguageTranslator.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    public static String translate(String msg) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return messageSource.getMessage(msg, null, locale);
    }
}
```

And here is my postman request
[image]
and here is messages_fr.properties

[image]
and project structure
[image]

And here is my controller code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeContoller {

    @Autowired
    private SystemSettingService settingService;



    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {

        return "Home page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity all_menu_assignment(HttpServletRequest req)  {
   

        return  ResponseEntity
                .ok().body(new ServerResponse(Common.SUCCESS_CODE,Common.SUCCESS_MESSAGE));

    }
}
```

and here is my Common class

```
public class Common{
  public static String SUCCESS_MESSAGE= LanguageTranslator.translate("SUCCESS_MESSAGE");
}
```

Comment: Please share the curl request from Postman. Also, make sure the header Accept-Language is set properly

Comment: @karthik check updated question

Comment: Can u list the controller code?

Comment: @karthik check updated code with controller

Comment: @karthik My Common class is calling that function to translate check update class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LocaleContextHolder` holds the locale of the current thread - so referencing this in a static variable will result in the default VM local to be used (because the constant will be initialized during startup).

Something like this should work:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeContoller {

    @Autowired
    private SystemSettingService settingService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {

        return "Home page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity all_menu_assignment(HttpServletRequest req)  {
   

        return  ResponseEntity
                .ok().body(new ServerResponse(Common.SUCCESS_CODE, LanguageTranslator.translate("SUCCESS_MESSAGE")));

    }
}
```

Also, it would be better make the `translate` method in `LanguageTranslator` non-static and to inject (autowire) the object in the controller.

Comment: You see My Common class already has that function

Comment: Changed the answer to match your changed question.

Comment: thanks a lot my mistake was me using static to access fields

Answer (score 0):

Translator.toLocale(Common.SUCCESS_MESSAGE) is missing in your controller api method

Comment: My Common class is calling that function to translate